# Why do I get a Typescript ts(2345) error when I pass my mocked constant to .mockResolvedValue()?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, jestjs

Take the following code inside of my test.tsx file.

```
 test('Photos will load', async () => {
    const mockCuratedPhotos = jest.spyOn(endpoints, 'getCuratedPhotos');
    mockCuratedPhotos.mockResolvedValue(mockPhotos);
    await render(<Home />)
    let element = screen.getByText('Home');
    let search = screen.getByTestId('search')
    expect(element).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(search).toBeInTheDocument();
})
```

I'm trying to write tests using jest and React Testing Library in an Next.js app. I'm mocking my API calls so that my component will load with mockPhotos, but I can see that my data isn't loading in my test. The Typescript compiler is throwing the following error:

`Argument of type 'Photos[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Photos | ErrorResponse | Promise<Photos | ErrorResponse | undefined> | undefined'.ts(2345)`

My mock data is literally a snippet taken from the actual API GET call so I know that it's format is accurate. Why is Typescript complaining? I thought when I use `mockResolvedValue()` The component is just suppose to accept that this is the data that it will receive.

// Actual API function

```
 export const getCuratedPhotos = async (page?: number) => {
  const client = createClient(key);
  try {
    if (!page) {
      return await client.photos.curated({ per_page: 10 });
    } else {
      return await client.photos.curated({ per_page: 10, page });
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('error', e);
  }
}
```

// mocked const

```
export const mockPhotos: Array<Photos> = [
{
    "page": 1,
    "per_page": 10,
    "photos": [
         {
            "id": 15823317,
            "width": 4043,
            "height": 6064,
            "url": "https://www.pexels.com/photo/love-summer-sun-leaf-15823317/",
            "photographer": "Mathilde Langevin",
            "photographer_url": "https://www.pexels.com/@mathilde",
            "photographer_id": 157994802,
            "avg_color": "#9B9887",
            "src": {
                "original": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/15823317/pexels-photo-15823317.jpeg",
                "large2x": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/15823317/pexels-photo-15823317.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940",
                "large": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/15823317/pexels-photo-15823317.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940",
                "medium": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/15823317/pexels-photo-15823317.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350",
                "small": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/15823317/pexels-photo-15823317.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=130",
                "portrait": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/15823317/pexels-photo-15823317.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&h=1200&w=800",
                "landscape": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/15823317/pexels-photo-15823317.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&h=627&w=1200",
                "tiny": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/15823317/pexels-photo-15823317.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&fit=crop&h=200&w=280"
            },
            "liked": false,
            "alt": ""
        },
        {
         etc...
        }
    ],
    "total_results": 8000,
    "next_page": "https://api.pexels.com/v1/curated/?page=3&per_page=10",
    "prev_page": "https://api.pexels.com/v1/curated/?page=1&per_page=10"
}
]
```

Comment: `Photos[]` indeed isn't `Photos | ErrorResponse | undefined` or a promise resolving to such, so `mockPhotos` _isn't_ a valid return value from `endpoints.getCuratedPhotos`. Without a [mre] it's hard to say where the problem is, though - at least one of those types is wrong, but we can't tell you which.

Comment: Would it be helpful if I post the API function and the constant?

Comment: Please give a MRE per the link above, so other people can actually reproduce the problem locally.

Comment: Wrap `mockPhotos` in a `Promise.resolve()` like [this doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve)

Comment: What type signature does the `client.photos.curated()` method have?

Comment: @RandyCasburn Promise.resolve() doesn't seem to work, but mockCuratedPhotos.mockResolvedValue(new Promise(() => mockPhotos)); removes the error. Unfortunately my data still doesn't appear to be loading though.

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek I'm not exactly sure what you mean? Here are the docs. https://www.pexels.com/api/documentation?language=javascript#photos-curated

Comment: `.mockResolvedValue(new Promise(() => mockPhotos))` is a `Promise<undefined>` (valid type) that _never resolves_. `.mockResolvedValue` already turns the value into a promise, so the promise constructor is totally redundant anyway.

Comment: I thought so seeing as I've never had to use it the past. Why do you think it removes the error then?

Comment: @London804 because one of the accepted types to `.mockResolvedValue()` is `Promise<undefined>` and `new Promise(() => mockPhotos)` creates precisely that type of value. So TypeScript will not complain about the type anymore but that does not change the reality - which in this case means no data at all, because this Promise will never resolve.

Comment: Okay, but isn't the whole point of mockResolvedValue to simple pass a value to the component? To be clear the bigger problem I'm having is my data is not loading in my test. @SebastianKaczmarek

Comment: @London804 have you tried following my advice from the answer below? Is the data still not passed?

Comment: Yes, that didn't make a difference. I'm still seeing the ts error and my mockPhotos are not being passed to my component for the test.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have misunderstood the API response. I suppose you are using this API: https://www.pexels.com/api/documentation/?language=javascript#photos-curated

If that's true, you can see that the response always contains only **one page at a time**. If you want to get more pages, you make another request with the `next_page` value.

In your case it means that you should use `Photos` type instead of `Array<Photos>` for the `mockedPhotos` variable. Like this:

```
export const mockPhotos: Photos = {
    "page": 1,
    "per_page": 10,
    "photos": [
         {
            "id": 15823317,
            "width": 4043,
            "height": 6064,
            "url": "https://www.pexels.com/photo/love-summer-sun-leaf-15823317/",
            "photographer": "Mathilde Langevin",
            "photographer_url": "https://www.pexels.com/@mathilde",
            "photographer_id": 157994802,
            "avg_color": "#9B9887",
            "src": {
                "original": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/15823317/pexels-photo-15823317.jpeg",
                "large2x": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/15823317/pexels-photo-15823317.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940",
                "large": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/15823317/pexels-photo-15823317.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940",
                "medium": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/15823317/pexels-photo-15823317.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350",
                "small": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/15823317/pexels-photo-15823317.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=130",
                "portrait": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/15823317/pexels-photo-15823317.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&h=1200&w=800",
                "landscape": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/15823317/pexels-photo-15823317.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&h=627&w=1200",
                "tiny": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/15823317/pexels-photo-15823317.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&fit=crop&h=200&w=280"
            },
            "liked": false,
            "alt": ""
        },
        {
         etc...
        }
    ],
    "total_results": 8000,
    "next_page": "https://api.pexels.com/v1/curated/?page=3&per_page=10",
    "prev_page": "https://api.pexels.com/v1/curated/?page=1&per_page=10"
}
```

So as you can see there's only one page at a time, with the `page` key representing the current page, and the `photos` array with the actual photos.

The API does not return an array of pages - only one page at a time.